# Is there a way to always redirect users to "/_layouts/15/userdisp.aspx?ID=**" instead of "/my/Person.aspx?accountname=**"

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, user-profile, administration, my-site

I am working on a sharepoint farm 2013 on-premises. now when i click on some user names i will be redirected to this page:-

```
/my/Person.aspx?accountname=***
```

while for other users i will be redirected to this page:-

```
/_layouts/15/userdisp.aspx?ID=**
```

Now i checked this further and seems if the username have a user profile created, I will be redirected to the first page.. while if the user does not have a user profile i will be redirected to the second page. so is there a way to always force the redirection to the second page.. as at this stage i do not want to use my-sites for the users since this is a new farm, and i want to enable the my-sites at later stages..

Thanks

Comment: You can turn off the permission to create personal sites. Then they will only have a profile and no personal site.

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott from where i can define this permission?? and if i do so then this will always redirect users to the `/_layouts/15/userdisp.aspx?ID=**` page?

Comment: You change the permissions in the User Profile Service. You cannot change the redirection, if you have a UPS the redirection will take place. You can, however, prevent the creation of personal sites.

Answer (score 2):

if you have the user profile sync enabled in your farm then

- if user profile created and synced then you will be redirected to Profile page( pulled from UPA)

  - if User authenticated and browse the site collection then his profile will be created in UPA and properly sync (once timer jobs run).
  - but if you just added the users and his profile not exist in UPA & sync then you will get basic profile(2nd link in ur question).

But if you dont have profile sync enabled then you will get the 2nd link all the time for the all users as no profile sync will be there and SharePoint only gets the basic information i.e. account, name or workemail.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. now in my case i do not have the sync enabled,, but as you mentioned when a new user access a site collection, a new user profile will be created, and if i click on this username i will be redirected to this page `/my/Person.aspx?accountname=***` .. but if there is a user who have never access a site , and we click on his user name we will be redirected to this page `/_layouts/15/userdisp.aspx?ID=**` .. now what i am asking about if there is a way to always redirect to `/_layouts/15/userdisp.aspx?ID=**??regardless if the user profile exists or not...??

Comment: I am not sure if OOTB you can configure it. But you can write some custom code which can redirect to desired page.

Comment: now as suggested on the above comment by Matthew McDermott... is turning off the permission to create personal sites a way to try??

Comment: That will restrict for my site creation but not what u are looking